# $\lfloor a n\rfloor \lfloor b n\rfloor \lfloor c n\rfloor = \lfloor d n\rfloor \lfloor e n\rfloor \lfloor f n\rfloor$ for all $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Simple task, but I know only extremely overkill solution :)

> Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be positive irrational numbers.
>
> Suppose that for any positive integer number $n$,
>
> $$\lfloor a  n\rfloor \cdot \lfloor b  n\rfloor \cdot \lfloor c  n\rfloor  
> = \lfloor d n\rfloor \cdot \lfloor e  n\rfloor \cdot \lfloor f  n\rfloor.$$
>
> Prove that the sets $\{a,b,c\}$ and  $\{d,e,f\}$ are equal.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What fo you mean by {a,b,c} and what are you doing with the product of the floors?

Comment: {a,b,c} is an unordered set

Comment: Interesting question +1. It follows quickly that $abc = def$ from $\lim x / \lfloor x \rfloor = 1$. Would you have a simple (counter)example why the *irrational* condition is necessary.

Comment: @dxiv - I have no simple (counter)example, but my solution uses irrationality of (at least one) number

Comment: @dxiv

simple contrexample:
a=1 b=1 c=4
d=1 e=2 f=2

Comment: Thanks, but that's *too* simple ;-) I was wondering more about a counterexample with rationals in $(0,1)$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv

if all numbers a,b,c, d,e,f in (0, 1),  simple to prove what  {a, b, c} = {d,e,f}

let a>=b>=c, d>=e>=f, d>a.
See such n what na<nd+10, floor(nd) is prime.

Comment: @kotomord What is your overkill solution?

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I'll write it today (Sorry, I'm working now)
It uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Comment: @kotomord abcdef are irrational.

Comment: @kotomord Yeah, that's sort of what I assumed you were going to say :P

Comment: @JustKevin - it was an example to "irrational condition is necessary"

Comment: Maybe it is true, but I don't know solution for R-Z

Comment: Is this true more generally? say for $\lfloor an\rfloor\lfloor bn\rfloor\lfloor cn\rfloor\lfloor dn\rfloor=\lfloor en\rfloor\lfloor fn\rfloor\lfloor gn\rfloor\lfloor hn\rfloor$? or more terms?

Comment: marco2013 covered it in his proof.  Bravo!

Comment: @MiloBrandt my last answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the overkill  proof;

One of the equidistribution theorems:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

a is irrational, then sequence $a*p_n$ mod 1 is uniformly distributed.

Lemma: 
If a > 0 is irrational, then sequence { $\lfloor a*n\rfloor$ } contains infinitely many prime numbers.

Proof of lemma:

Case (a>1):

$\lfloor a*n\rfloor = p_m$ <=> $p_m < a*n < p_m + 1$  <=> $\frac{p_m}{a} < n < \frac{p_m+1}{a}$  <=> n =  $\lfloor \frac{p_m+1}{a}\rfloor$, {$\frac{p_m}{a}$} $ \in (1-\frac{1}{a}, 1)$  (where are infinitely many such m by thm.)

Case (a<1) is trivial.

Proof of task:

Without loss of generality $a \ge b \ge c, d \ge e \ge f, a\ge d$

Let a > d. 
Fix n what $n*a > n*d + 2, n*c > 1, \lfloor n*a \rfloor  =p_m$

$\lfloor n*d \rfloor \lfloor n*e \rfloor \lfloor n*f \rfloor  > 0 $ and not divisible to $p_m$ -  it is the absurd.

So, a = d and we need to prove what if $\lfloor n*e \rfloor \lfloor n*f \rfloor = \lfloor n*b \rfloor \lfloor n*c \rfloor$, then sets {b, c}  and {e,f} are equals.

We can do it similary or by method of @marco2013

P.S. Maybe, we can generalize lemma to rational not-integer numbers (with the Dirichlet thm.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $E=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^6$. Let $x=(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c},\overline{d},\overline{e},\overline{f})\in E$. Let $F=\mathbb{N}x$.

$\overline{F}$ is a subgroup of $E$.

$a,b,c,d,e,f$ are irrationnal, so it exists $(u_n)\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $(\delta_a,\delta_b,\delta_c,\delta_d,\delta_e,\delta_f)\in \{0,1\}^6$ such that $u_nx \in E \mapsto 0_E$ with $u_nx=(\overline{a_n},\overline{b_n},\overline{c_n},\overline{d_n},\overline{e_n},\overline{f_n})$ and $0<a_n<1,0<b_n<1,0<c_n<1,0<d_n<1 ,0<e_n<1 ,0<f_n<1$.

and $(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n,e_n,f_n)\in[0,1]^6 \mapsto (\delta_a,\delta_b,\delta_c,\delta_d,\delta_e,\delta_f)$.

So it exists $(v_n)\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $v_nx \in E \mapsto 0_E$ with $v_nx=(\overline{a'_n},\overline{b'_n},\overline{c'_n},\overline{d'_n},\overline{e'_n},\overline{f'_n})$ and $0<a'_n<1,0<b'_n<1,0<c'_n<1,0<d'_n<1 ,0<e'_n<1 ,0<f'_n<1$.

and $(a'_n,b'_n,c'_n,d'_n,e'_n,f'_n)\in[0,1]^6 \mapsto (1-\delta_a,1-\delta_b,1-\delta_c,1-\delta_d,1-\delta_e,1-\delta_f)$

So $\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor=(au_n-a_n) (bu_n-b_n)(cu_n-c_n)=abc(u_n)^3-abc_n(u_n)^2-acb_n(u_n)^2-bca_n(u_n)^2+\dots$

So, as already shown by **dxiv**, $$\lim\frac{\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor}{u_n^3}=abc$$

So $abc=def$ because $\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor=\lfloor du_n\rfloor \lfloor eu_n\rfloor \lfloor fu_n\rfloor$

And $$\lim \frac{\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor-abc(u_n)^3}{u_n^2}=-ab\delta_c-ac\delta_b -bc\delta_a$$

We have also $$\lim \frac{\lfloor av_n\rfloor \lfloor bv_n\rfloor \lfloor cv_n\rfloor-abc(v_n)^3}{v_n^2}=-ab(1-\delta_c)-ac(1-\delta_b) -bc(1-\delta_a)$$

So $$ab+ac+bc=-\lim \frac{\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor-abc(u_n)^3}{u_n^2}-\lim \frac{\lfloor av_n\rfloor \lfloor bv_n\rfloor \lfloor cv_n\rfloor-abc(v_n)^3}{v_n^2}$$

So $ab+ac+bc=de+df+ef$.

**Lemma**: We show $\overline{F}=\overline{\mathbb{N}x}$ is a subgroup. For all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let the compact $A_k=kx+\overline{\mathbb{N}x}\subset \overline{\mathbb{N}x}$. And for all $k$, $0\in A_k$. So $0 \in G=\cap_k A_k$. $x+G\subset G$. So $\mathbb{N}x+G\subset G$.

$G$ is compact so $\overline{\mathbb{N}x}\subset G$.

As $G \subset A_0=\overline{\mathbb{N}x}$, we have $G=\overline{\mathbb{N}x}$.

As $0 \in\overline{\mathbb{N}x}=G \subset A_1=x+\overline{\mathbb{N}x}$, we have $-x\in \overline{\mathbb{N}x}$. So $ \overline{\mathbb{N}x}= \overline{\mathbb{Z}x}$

**Remark**: for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we can choose $(\delta_a,\delta_b,\dots,\delta_f)=(\{ma\},\{mb\},\dots,\{mf\})\in \overline{F}$, and $(u_n)$ such that $u_n x\mapsto \delta$. So we have $ab\{mc\}+ac\{mb\}+bc\{ma\}=de\{mf\}+df\{me\}+ef\{md\}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But you have no proof what a+b+c = d+e+f?

Comment: No, but my comment was too long.

Comment: I use the property: $\overline{F}$ is a subgroup. So if $(\overline{y_1},\overline{y_2},\overline{y_3},\overline{y_4},\overline{y_5},\overline{y_6})\in \overline{F}$, we have $(\overline{1-y_1},\overline{1-y_2},\overline{1-y_3},\overline{1-y_4},\overline{1-y_5},\overline{1-y_6})\in \overline{F}$ too.

Comment: In your lemma, why do we have $0\in A_k$ ?

Comment: Because $E$ is compact. So from the sequence $nx$, we can find a subsequence $w_nx\mapsto \ell\in E$ (with $w_n$ strictly increasing). Let$\epsilon>0$,$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\implies \|w_nx-\ell\|<\epsilon$. So $\forall n,m>N$, $\|(w_n-w_m)x\|<2\epsilon$. Take $w_n-w_m>k$. So $0\in \overline{A_k}$. But $A_k$ is compact.

Comment: I mean $d(a,b)$ instead of $\|a-b\|$. Notice $d(a,b)=d(a-b,0)$

Comment: Thank for answering my questions, I removed my downvote. I think you can also show that $a+b+c=d+e+f$ (which would finish the proof). Indeed, $a+b+c$ is the limit when $n\to\infty$ of something like $\frac{\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor-abc(u_n)^3-(ab+ac+bc)u_n^2}{u_n}-\frac{\lfloor av_n\rfloor \lfloor bv_n\rfloor \lfloor cv_n\rfloor-abc(v_n)^3-(ab+ac+bc)v_n^2}{v_n}$, is it not ?

Comment: Maybe, but $\lfloor au_n\rfloor \lfloor bu_n\rfloor \lfloor cu_n\rfloor=(au_n-a_n)(bu_n-b_n)(cu_n-c_n)=abc(u_n)^3-ab(u_n)^2\mathbf{c_n}+ \dots+au_n\mathbf{b_nc_n}+\dots-a_nb_nc_n$

Comment: I don't quite follow how you obtain $v_n$.

Comment: Also, notice that $0<a_nb_nc_n < 1$, so that terms goes to $0$ in the limit.