# Vector space spanned by $(\{na_1\},\{na_2\},\dots,\{na_k\})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, vector-spaces

Let $a_1,a_2, \dots,a_k$ positive irrational numbers. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $v_n=(\{na_1\},\{na_2\},\dots,\{na_k\})\in\mathbb{R}^k$, let $F\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ the vector space spanned by $(v_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. If $\dim F \leq k-1$, can we deduce that $\exists i,j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$, such that $i\neq j $ and $\{a_i\}=\{a_j\}$ ?

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021213/lfloor-a-n-rfloor-lfloor-b-n-rfloor-lfloor-c-n-rfloor-lfloor-d-n-rfloor/2027260#2027260), because, in the related question, we have $ab\{nc\}+ac\{nb\}+bc\{na\}-de\{nf\}-df\{ne\}-ef\{nd\}=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.